# Combining resistors in series with a voltage source in between

Tags: resistors

[image]

Am I allowed to combine the resistor **R** and coil **Xl** as if they were right next to each other? I want to make this into a current generator, without many transformations.

Comment: Usually inductors available in the market have internal resistance hence they are like series resistance with inductance also.

Comment: If your voltage source is DC, as you've indicated, then you're stuck.

Comment: It's an ideal AC voltage source. Anything changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only combine two single elements into one for sake of analysis if they are in series with nothing else connected to the node between them, or if they are in parallel with nothing else connected in series between them.

So, do Xl and Z meet either of these criteria?  If not, why not?

Comment: They don't. (90% confident)

Comment: Desp: Right.  However, I see two obvious candidates that can be combined.

Comment: find impedance Z so it dissipates most power. I need to get everything into series.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can combine these.

However you change that circuit in some way. If you did a circuit analysis before using e.g. matrices to describe the circuit, those aren't valid any longer.

In real world you probably have reference potential points (i.e. earth points, housing, etc.) which are omitted in this simplified circuit but are often in a relation (i.e. connected) with a voltage source. Rearranging circuit elements in a real circuit may change its behaviour due to such influences.